# Office 365 Share Calendar with OU

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365, outlook-web-access

How do I tell folks how to share their calendar with a list of addresses?

Preferred solution would be to use an Active Directory group instead of individuals. Possible?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate on ServerFault - Creating a Dynamic Group in Active Directory with users from a OU - http://serverfault.com/questions/488365/creating-a-dynamic-group-in-active-directory-with-users-from-a-ou

Answer (score 0):

Yes Possible. I thought it wasn't working because we had ad AD group that failed. Turned out this was a 'distribution' group (attribute?) and we needed a 'security' group (or attribute on the exiting group) before we could use the OU group for permission tasks.